# Matching with _branch_match_id across devices

Tags: branch.io

On my website I use QR-code to bring users from desktop directly to relevant app store on their mobiles (surprisingly it works very good with ~50% conversion).

I append get-parameters from the website's url to the link backed into QR-code (it's generating dynamically).

I tested the flow when users get to my website from the branch links (it's a Desktop Default url). When they go to mobile via QR they stop matching with initial link, even despite the fact they have `_branch_match_id` in url.

Shouldn't `_branch_match_id` be valid across platforms/devices? Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_branch_match_id is generated dynamically each time Branch matches a link click to an app open/install/web session start event.

The match id you get in your website's URL is for the match between the click the user made and the web session start event. You cannot pass the same match id in your QR code.

A correct way to implement this would be to integrate the Branch's web SDK into your app and read the link from which the user came to your web page's branch.init() and then generate a QR code for the same link.

Another way you can do this is by reading the params of the initial branch link that was clicked and then creating a new Branch link with the same params.

In any case, you need to use the Branch's Web SDK.

You can also refer here - https://docs.branch.io/web/integrate/#integrate-branch